# Catching SMS send and deliver event

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I'm sending SMS from my app. I'm able to do that successfully on devices with service providers but on some tablet devices and emulator where service provider is not available, I want to display corresponding error message.I'm using following code for that (referred from [this link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)):

```
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

                PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        ClipResultActivity.this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

                PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        ClipResultActivity.this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED),
                        0);

                // ---when the SMS has been sent---
                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "SMS not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

                // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
                registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                        if (getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

                SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                sms.sendTextMessage(PHONE_NO, null, SMS_BODY, sentPI,
                        deliveredPI);
```

But any of the `BroadcastReceiver` is not getting executed on devices with no service provider. I was expecting both `BroadcastReceiver` to get executed and return negative responses.

Please note that I have **NOT ADDED** anything related to `BroadcastReceiver` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Though I have added SMS permissions.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I would go about it another way, by checking if the device is a tablet or handset, and if it is a HANDSET then check if it has a SIM or not, and if it DOES, then check if it has a service or not, and then show an error message

Comment: Suggested answer has short and simple way to do this. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: but it might fail if that is a mobile device without a SIM...

Comment: in such case, it will show, sms sent without actually sending the sms, right?

Comment: Wait! My first instinct was to say yes, but I'm not really sure... this might break down and crash depends on the OS, and the underlying implementation... You can test this easily, take phone and take the SIM out and send an SMS with your application, and see what happens. Also check this on an older version!

Comment: Ok, sounds good. I'll definitely test it and will let u know !

Comment: I tested it on Android 2.3 and Android 4.0, it says - *SMS Sent*...

Comment: And did it?  I would guess not! After inserting the SIM back, were the SMSs send? I would still guess not! Thus a proper error dialog in this case is required!

Comment: SMSs were not sent. It just gave the Toast msg with *SMS Sent*. I'll be handling this scenario now. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rowItem is my holder class for my listview. I am calling `onItemSelectedListener` on specific item, so for your tablet or any other device, my code works. If there is no support for SMS, then it show Toast.

```
if(rowItems.get(position).getTitle().endsWith("SMS"))
        {
            if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY))
            {   
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.putExtra("address", "0"+9999999999);
                intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
            else {
                toast("No SMS Support");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Straightforward and simple : `if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY))` Thanks a ton, mate !